# In-app advertising with MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, ads

I'm using MonoTouch for an iPhone game, just wondering: is it possible to implement in-app advertising using MonoTouch and if so how would I go about doing it?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet would be using the iAd framework which has been bound. (`Monotouch.iAd`)

**edit**

To help you get started: [See this blog post](http://blog.manniat.net/post/2010/07/04/iAD-with-Monotouch.aspx)

Comment: oh right, and it should be ok to use the iAd framework in conjunction with the fact monotouch is using opengl? (sorry I'm a total newbie to this!)

Comment: Are you using `glView` rather than a `UIViewController`?

Comment: Then you should be AOK to use iAd as normal !

Comment: Note if you find it crashes on the device, there is a fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819952/monotouch-app-with-iads-runs-on-simulator-crashes-on-device