# MonoTouch NSClassFromString

Tags: c#, .net, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use code such as the following Objective-C in MonoTouch:

`if (NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView"))`

What is the equivalent in C#?

Basically I'm wanting to use iAd, but I need to check for the existance of `ADBannerView` and `ADInterstitialAd`, because they are not available on all versions of the OS.  (And I'd rather do feature checking than iOS version checking)

I think this could be helpful in other situations as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recent MonoTouch will always provide `ADBannerView` so you cannot the the C# equivalent of `Type.GetType` to query availability.

Normally a version check is the best way to check for features. E.g.

```
bool available = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (4, 0);
```

will return **true** for any 4.0+ versions of iOS (4.0 being when `ADBannerView` was added to iOS).

A possible alternative (might not work in every case) is to create an instance and check it's handle. Since ObjC is message based sending `init` will return null (something a .NET constructor can't do). E.g.

```
bool available = (new ADBannerView ().Handle != IntPtr.Zero);
```

Note that you probably best surround the above with `using` to dispose the view or integrate this inside the normal creation of your `ADBannerView`.

**UPDATE**: of course a p/invoke to [`NSClassFromString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString) would do *exactly* the same as the ObjectiveC code :-)

Comment: Do you have an example of the p/invoke?  Would this work: `[DllImport (Constants.FrameworkLibrary)] public static extern IntPtr NSClassFromString(string className);`

Comment: I have not tried it but it should be `[DllImport (Constants.FoundationLibrary)]`, otherwise it looks like what I would try (sorry packing for wwdc ;-)

Comment: I'll send you a coupon code for the pro version when it's done, thanks.

Comment: Since then, I've discovered: `MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.GetHandle ("ADBannerView")`    I think this should be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

This person asked the question and answered it.  It looks like you need compiler flags:

Check this out: [MonoTouch app with iAds runs on simulator, crashes on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819952/monotouch-app-with-iads-runs-on-simulator-crashes-on-device)

Otherwise you can [Check for class in an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1138426/353147).

Lastly you can use the same google search I did: [monotouch ADBannerView assembly](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1DVCC_enUS346&sugexp=chrome,mod=2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23+check+for+class+in+assembly#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&rlz=1C1DVCC_enUS346&q=monotouch+ADBannerView+assembly&oq=monotouch+ADBannerView+assembly&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_l=serp.3...116227.120875.0.121206.20.20.0.0.0.0.151.2291.7j13.20.0.ekh.1.0.0.syFKB6SgCF8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=26b20b30f12ed1d6&biw=1285&bih=1082)

If this doesn't help, one of the guys at MonoTouch usually check for monotouch tagged questions and are really helpful.

Comment: I just need to call `NSClassFromString` from C#.  Your solutions aren't exactly what I need--I'm building a custom ad framework, and I need to detect if particular feature of iAd is available.  For example, `ADInterstitialAd` was introduced in iOS 4.2 or something (don't quote me), so I need to detect that and provide a backfilled ad from another provider.  Checking for a class in an assembly with always be true, because the MonoTouch class always exists.